# Can't parse json response in Jmeter

Tags: json, postgresql, jdbc, jmeter, jsonpath

I try to parse JSON response with jmeter and then use parsed value in JDBC request. I have a Json path like:

```
$.response..assignments..organizationId
```

but when I use the variable in my future requests, the result is:

```
select u.external_id from mr_department d, sec_group g, sec_user u where d.external_id = '["666"]'
```

So it's not a variable but json small file. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it depends on the json response, the expected value is an array so the correct Json Path is

```
$.response..assignments..organizationId[0]
```